# Why spring security logout does not work?

Tags: java, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

I have a problem with spring security, I try to logout in spring security,but it seem does not work.I request the logout url, but the session and auth does not clear.

This is for a spring cloud application, running spring cloud Finchley.RELEASE.Use zuul,spring security and oauth2.

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login","/login.html").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .successHandler(loginSuccessHandler)
            .failureHandler(loginFailHandler)
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout"))
            .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutHandler)
            .clearAuthentication(true)
            .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
            .invalidateHttpSession(true);

    http .cors().and().csrf().disable();

}
```

I expect after request logout url,the authentication and session is invalid

Answer (score 1):

Use below code in your logoutHandler.

```
@Service
@Scope(scopeName = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_SINGLETON)
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
public class CustomLogoutSuccessHandler implements LogoutSuccessHandler{

    @Override
    public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest,
            HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse, Authentication authentication)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        if (authentication != null && authentication.getDetails() != null) {
            try {
                httpServletRequest.getSession().invalidate();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        httpServletResponse.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        httpServletResponse.sendRedirect("/");
    }
}
```